# Where should we store data (files) from users in Laravel architecture?

Tags: laravel

I have a project that is meant to work for some countries. For now, in this example lets says USA-(`us`) and France-(`fr`).

So, when the user write in the URL `us_mySite.com`, the system should open the files, or display some pictures related to us only, not fr

At some point the user will need to update some file (pdf, excel, pictures, videos, etc) and the system must store these files inside the correct country.

So now we have in the site root a structure like this:

```
www/myStie/
      ...
      ...
      data/
       us/
         excel/
         pdf/
       fr/ ... 

      img/
       us/
       fr/
      ...
      ...
```

Now I am migrating the system to Laravel 5 and I would like to know where should I put this data folder. Should it be inside `Public/`  folder? This folder should be accessible for delete, read, changes and save files trough the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quote from laravel doc: https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-public-directory

> The **storage/app/public** directory may be used to store user-generated
>   files, such as profile avatars, that should be publicly accessible.
>   You should create a **symbolic link at public/storage** which points to
>   this directory. You may create the link using the php artisan
>   storage:link command.

Comment: for some reason if I put it inside `storage/app/public/` I got a broked link when I load the page. Path is correct. Have an idea what is heppening. I am using windows.

Answer (score 0):

Store them in public folder.
https://laravel.com/docs/master/structure#the-public-directory.

That's where all the assets go. Check the above link for more info.

Comment: BTW, If you put them in the resources folder you'll have better control of them and show them when you need to.